The periodic solutions of the equation : $\theta^{"}+\sin(\theta)+2k\theta=0.$
I am working on the problem of coupled pendulums and I am trying to find the periodic solutions of the equation :  $\theta^{"}+\sin(\theta)+2k\theta=0.$
I have put the variable change$X=\pmatrix{\theta\\ \theta'}$, to get  $X'=\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\-2k & 0}X+\pmatrix{0 \\-\sin(\theta)}=AX+f$. I have also tried by variation of constant but I can't complete the problem ! Any help is really appreciated !

This is not a linear equation, so standard textbook method won't work. The usual approach is to assume $\theta$ is small and use the approximation $\sin(\theta)\approx \theta$ to make a linear ODE.

Hint: For a system of the form $x'' + f(x) = 0$, $E(x,x') = \frac{1}{2}(x')^2 + \int_a^x f(s)ds$ is a conserved quantity so trajectories must lie on level curves of this function

Thanks you ! the following quantity is conserved $E_k=\frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{2}+1-\cos (\theta)+k \theta^2$ and this is the equation of an ellipse ! (?)

Not the equation of an ellipse due to the $\cos\theta$ term, but you can still prove things about its level sets

Can you please elaborate or give me a good reference ? (Thanks you so much)
